# c# ListView items checkbox to be flat styled

Tags: c#, listview, user-interface, checkbox, listviewitem

Enabling `Checkboxes` in `ListView` control provides standard style checkboxes

Can we change that standard look to flat style?

Here is how checkboxes appeared in `ListView` [[listview checkboxes image]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dl1Jo.png) 
 and here is how i want it to be like [[flat checkbox image]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jGedy.png)

i checked `ListViewItem` source and i couldn't find checkbox control so that i can change its style.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It looks flat on my W10. You may try to owner-draw them..

Comment: i though of owner-draw but it is useless in my situation. because i have a `ListView` that populates dynamically. i can't predefine a fixed styling layout using `DrawItem` or any of owner-draw functtions

Comment: Hm, well  - sure you can't write the DrawItem in a way that is flexible enough? It is called separately for each item and you can access all sorts of info on the items..

Comment: @TaW i'm not sure but i don't know how to draw a flat checkbox that inherits the `ListViewItem ` properties like `ListViewItem.Checked` and so

Comment: THere is a class to draw all sorts of controls in all their states. See [the link to controlpaint here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/rendering-controls-with-visual-styles)